# Drop tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database with tables some examples named "_data", "_keep", "foo", "bar"

Without dropping all tables in Db, 
How do I drop all tables that dont start with "_". In above example foo and bar.

Using Sql

Having problem with keywords used as table names, is there away to Not to drop "_" but drop any tables older than 10 minutes.  (I wanted to drop before table creation. now looking to do drop after update.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set @str = (select concat('drop table ', group_concat(table_name separator ','),';')
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'your_database_name' and table_name not regexp '^_');
prepare stmt from @str;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

edit. I answer you here because it's more readable.
If you want to retrieve only tables created more than 10 minutes ago you have to do

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'your_db'
and now() - interval 10 minute > create_time
```

Apply where clause to my previous code.
I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I haven't tested but take a look at David sp. :)

Comment: How could I set this up as a Stored procedure using Input of Database?

Comment: Having prob with some tables names they use keywords-cant control. Is there a way do not drop "_" and drop older than 10 minutes.

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood. My english is poor. Do you want to drop only tables created more than 10 minutes ago?

Comment: Yes, anything 10 minutes ago.

Answer (score 4):

```
delimiter $$
create procedure drop_tables_like(pattern varchar(255), db varchar(255))
begin
select @str_sql:=concat('drop table ', group_concat(table_name))
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema=db and table_name like pattern;

prepare stmt from @str_sql;
execute stmt;
drop prepare stmt;
end$$

call drop_tables_like('_%', 'db_1')$$

drop procedure if exists drop_tables_like$$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: +1 Nice job. I've tested it. You have to escape _, otherwise it drops all tables. call drop_tables_like('\_%', 'importa');
There is a backslash before %. Forum eats it :) Maybe you had already put it and simply I can't see it. I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

The following line:

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p [password] --add-drop-table --no-data [databasename]|grep ^DROP
```

produces a list of all tables, like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `agenda`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bla`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
```

Filter that list with "grep" and pipe it back into mysql.

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p [password] --add-drop-table --no-data [databasename] | \
    grep -E "^DROP TABLE IF EXISTS .[^_]" | mysql -u [username] -p [password] [databasename]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [mk-find](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-find.html). It will allow you to run commands against your server, and, based on the results of those commands, run other commands.